# Typescript: ignore event passed props, accept multiple prop names

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got an app which has a lot of modals. I wrote a fn which maps each modal to open and close fns, so i get syntax like this:

```
open.modalname(timeout, callback, props)
```

I'm using react, and in some cases i pass the open fn to onClick callback, which injects an event, which i have no use for, so i have a helper fn which ignores it.

These are the function types i've got

```
export type Output<T extends Object, F> = Record<keyof T, F>;

export type Open = Output<
  typeof modals,
  (
    timeout?: number | React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> | object,
    callback?: number | (() => void),
    props?: object | (() => void),
    _?: object | (() => void)
  ) => void
>;

export type Close = Output<typeof modals, () => void>;
```

I'm allowing 2 syntaxes in my helper: (timeout?, callback:?, props?)
or (props?)

Is there a way to write the Open type so i get a nicer autocomplete but allow all the possible types. eg:

```
(timeout?: number, callback?: () => void, props?: object) | (props?: object)
```

Comment: AKA overloads AKA intersections of function types AKA multiple call signatures

Comment: Does this work for you? https://tsplay.dev/m3BB1N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a function type that essentially has multiple [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Since overloads are really intersections of function types, you can use [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types). Do note that function types must be wrapped in parentheses to avoid ambiguity when used in intersections and unions.

```
type Open = ((timeout?: number, callback?: () => void, props?: object) => void) & ((props?: object) => void);
```

However, this can get a little clunky if you have a lot of overloads. Consider switching to [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) instead of intersections. The syntax is different, but they essentially achieve the same thing here.

```
type Open = {
    (timeout?: number, callback?: () => void, props?: object): void;
    (props?: object): void;
};
```

[Playground (intersections)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gIyRgFgFzwAUJGAlgLYhICuGA-MSnVdiDADSJQQTYoYANbNSASngBeAHzwAbkgrAeABxhJVaMUmwArcBkmyFS4JIBkpEus3biug2CPS5i5eIBQngPQ-4AJ4gaAp8yt64BCQAjAAMsTwkxnIA3gC+POlekfgkWd5+8Ch4oRDhnjkkAESYMBQoAOZV2Xi5GDB0IC1R6TzRAEwAzOJAA)

[Playground (call signatures)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gIyRgFgFzwDeAUPJfABQYCWAtiEgK4YD8xKLD2IMAGkRQIEbFDABrTjQCU8ALwA+eADckdYEIAOMJNrQyk2AFbgMs4us0BuClWq79h4sbNgLVjcDsBfO2QA9IHwAJ4gaGoimmRkuATUAIwADMlC1PLKpL5CJL6ycXj41HkFQSEoeFEQMYUJAESYMHQoAOb1BfHFGDAsIJ1FJTnwiQBMAMyyQA)

Answer (score 0):

I genuinely have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but if you just want to accept different options per function call, why not just do:

```js
export interface OpenFn {
  (options?: {
    event?: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    timeout?: number,
    callback?: () => void,
    props?: object,
  }): void
}

const open: OpenFn = (options = {}) => {
  const { 
    event,
    timeout,
    callback, 
    props,
  } = options;
  // logic
  // ...
}
```